# Count loop not working correctly in python with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

this is the code

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
Live = []
Sim = False
info = pygame.display.Info()
DH= (info.current_h//10)*10
DW = (info.current_w//10)*10
win = pygame.display.set_mode((DH,DW),pygame.RESIZABLE)
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    buttons = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if buttons[0]:
        Mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        X = (Mouse[0]//10)*10
        Y = (Mouse[1]//10)*10
        if Live.count((X,Y)) == 0:
            Live.append((X,Y))
            pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,255,255),(X,Y,10,10))
    pygame.display.update()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys [pygame.K_SPACE]:
        Sim = True
    while Sim:
        print("DONE")
        Count = 0
        for SX in range(0,DW,10):
            for SY in range(0,DH,10):
                List = [(0,10),(10,10),(10,0),(-10,10),(-10,-10),(-10,0),(0,-10),(10,-10)]
                for ADD in List:
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            pygame.quit()
                    AX = ADD[0]
                    AY = ADD[1]
                    TX = SX + AX
                    TY = SY + AY
                    for IND in range(len(Live)):
                        LiveCord = Live[IND]
                        LX = LiveCord[0]
                        LY = LiveCord[1]
                        if LX == TX and LY == TY:
                            Count = Count + 1
                    if Count >= 3:
                        pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,255,255),(SX,SY,10,10))
                        if Live.count((SX,SY)) == 0:
                            Live.append((SX,SY))
                    else:
                        pygame.draw.rect(win,(0,0,0),(SX,SY,10,10))
                    Count = 0
        pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

the Variable (int) Count is either a 1 or a 0 although it should be infinite so every time it just renders Black pixels the rule is if a pixel has 3 or more white pixels around it it lives is it has less it dies however this is not working because the count is not working

Answer (score 2):

This is the only place in your code where `Count` is incremented:

```
if LX == TX and LY == TY:
    Count = Count + 1
```

So, it seems like you expected this `if` statement to be true a lot more often than it actually is.

As a first debugging step, you can add some print statements so you can see exactly what is happening:

```
if LX == TX and LY == TY:
    Count = Count + 1
    print(f"{LX} == {TX} and {LY} == {TY}.  Count is now {Count}")
else:
    print(f"{LX} != {TX} and/or {LY} != {TY}.  Count is still {Count}")
```

When you see this output, it should provide a clue as to why the code isn't doing what you expect.